# How to make field on account only editable by admin?

Tags: users

How can I make it so that a certain field on the user profile/account is only editable by an admin?  I added the "file" field to accounts, but I want admin's to be the only ones to be able to populate the field.  I dont think there are permissions for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module to set permissions for a single field.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Features:

- Enable field permissions on any entity, not just nodes.
- Role-based field permissions allowing different viewing patterned based on what access the user has.
- Author-level permissions allow viewing and editing of fields based on who the entity owner is.
- Permissions for each field are not enabled by default. Instead, administrators can enable these permissions explicitly for the fields where this feature is needed.